# Startup of program run as a service fails

Tags: linux, startup

At boot time I want to start the *Pidgin Instant Messenger* on a system running *Bodhi Linux 5.1.0*.

On boot, the user is automatically logged in.

It works fine when I start it manually from the GUI.

When I hit `/usr/bin/pidgin` from a terminal window, it also starts.

With *nano* I created and saved:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/pidgin.service
```

Contents:

```
Description=Pidgin Instant Messenger

Wants=network.target
After=syslog.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/pidgin
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I reloaded all services, enabled, and started the service:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable pidgin
sudo systemctl start pidgin
```

This shows it as enabled:

```
sudo systemctl list-unit-files --type=service
```

But...:

```
sudo systemctl status pidgin.service
```

...shows in red:

```
Process: 3915 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pidgin (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 3915 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

What did I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After some digging through the menus, I found the solution there - no fiddling in terminal mode necessary.

FWIW, for those who use *Bodhi Linux* with the *Moksha* desktop:

```
Menu, Settings, Settings Panel
Apps, Startup Applications, Applications
CLICK Pidgin Internet Messenger
+ Add
Apply, Close
CLOSE Settings Panel
```

Restart the PC to test if it works.

Obviously, any other GUI application can be started this way when the system (re)boots.